# Bluetooth not detecting devices with ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, bluetooth

Sorry to ask a repetitive question. 
I read and tried multiple solutions posted in last 3 to 4 hours but couldn't succeed.
Bluetooth ON and visibility ON  but neither detect any device nor visible to other devices.

I 'm not good with Ubuntu, not even know that what exactly following commands do ,
can someone point me towards right direction

output of **lsusb** is

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lspci -knn | grep Net -A2; lsusb**

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b52d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0a5c:216d Broadcom Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

output of
    **rfkill list**

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: brcmwl-0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

For **dkms status**

```
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.4.0-72-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.4.0-75-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.4.0-78-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.4.0-79-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.4.0-81-generic, x86_64: installed
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.4.0-83-generic, x86_64: installed
```

**dmesg | grep -i blue**

```
[   12.207904] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.21
[   12.207919] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[   12.207921] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[   12.207924] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[   12.207928] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[   12.541892] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[   12.557906] Bluetooth: hci0: faisal-HP-Notebook
[   12.557910] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[   12.709950] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[   12.709954] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[   14.711794] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   21.446442] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   21.446445] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   21.446448] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   58.953015] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   58.953020] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   58.953024] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
[  538.154130] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
[ 1088.482264] Bluetooth: hci0 urb ffff8802519c5cc0 failed to resubmit (2)
[ 1101.185972] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: chip id 70
[ 1101.201973] Bluetooth: hci0: faisal-HP-Notebook
[ 1101.201977] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM (001.001.011) build 0000
[ 1101.201993] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for brcm/BCM.hcd failed with error -2
[ 1101.201995] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: Patch brcm/BCM.hcd not found
[ 1103.205069] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x1003 tx timeout
```

Comment: If output of any command required
kindly let me know

Comment: sudo service bluetooth status
● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)

isn't it different

Comment: You need to install firmware `BCM.hcd`.

Comment: I tried using
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/r6q9zt59darq80n/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd
sudo cp BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-216c.hcd
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb

it removed the bcm.hcd error but didn't work

Comment: its not letting me to turn bluetooth on

Comment: Why do you try that file? You have a different device. I gave a link to an answer describing how to get the firmware.

Comment: I Tried that soln hours ago
If I try your link, will it work now?

Comment: You still don't have `/lib/firmware/brcm/BCM.hcd` according to the log. So you did something wrong.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61512/discussion-between-muhammad-faisal-iqbal-and-pilot6).